# Code proceed to error in using Net::OpenSSH

Tags: perl, api, module, system

I wrote a monitoring script to view some log progress, however I stuck with below code,

```
$fh = $ssh->capture("find $servers{$agent}{$log} -mmin +10") or die "Unable to run command\n";
                        chomp($fh);

                        if ($fh) {
                                print "Log are 10 minutes not moving. \n";
                        }
                        else {
                                print "Log are running as usual. \n";
                        }
```

This code will come up with below output,

> Unable to run command

This indicated that there are an error occurred, however I try to run it manually through ssh the command works perfectly.

Need assistance to review this code.

Comment: Waht does `$ssh->error` say ?

Answer (score 0):

If `find` finds nothing, `capture` returns the empty string that is a false value, so the `die` gets called.

You can check if something went wrong calling the `error` method:

```
my $out = $ssh->capture("find $servers{$agent}{$log} -mmin +10");
$ssh->error and die "Unable to run command: " . $ssh->error;
```